# Merging symbols if close to each other geographically

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I have some point data categorized by TYPE, (each TYPE has a different symbol)

How can I merge the same TYPE of symbols if they are geographically closed to each other?

The size of the symbol should get bigger based on how many symbols are merged.

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

See the image for details:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these points were separated out into separate layers by type then you could use the dynamic clustering as discussed [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/aggregate-features-into-clusters.htm) applied to each layer?

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd for this, the points are not in separate layers,